# Error regarding the view function persists after running python code

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm still new to `python`, and there was this error after I run my python code.

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'elif'. You probably made a nesting mistake. Jinja is expecting this tag, but currently looking for 'endfor' or 'else'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'for'.

How can I solve this matter? My goal is to print all of the outputs in the given code in a html webpage. I already have an `html` webpage that asks users for their inputs. Currently, I'm using `flask`.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/index.css">
        <title>
            Project
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>
            Sample computation
        </h3>
        <p>
            <form action="/hello" method="post">
                Starting Location: <input type="text" name="starting"> 
                Destination: <input type="text" name="destination" />
                <input type="submit" name= "form" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </p>
        <p>
            {% if status == 0: %}
            <h1>
                Statistics
            </h1>
            <p>
                Directions from {{ firstPlace }} to {{ secondPlace }}
            </p>
            <p>
                Trip duration: {{ individual ["route"]["formattedTime"]}}
            </p>
            <br/>
            <h1>
                Distance in different units
            </h2>
            <p>
                Kilometers: {{ km }} <br/>
                Miles: {{ miles }} <br/>
                Yards: {{ yards }} <br/>
            </p>
            <h2>
                Fuel used in different units
            </h2>
            <p>
                Fuel Used (Ltr): {{ ltr }} <br/>
                Fuel Used (US Gal): {{ usGal }} <br/>
                Fuel Used (Imperial Gal): {{ impGal }} <br/>
            </p>
            {% for place in indi: %}
            <h3>
                Directions
            </h3>
            <p>
                {{ place }}
            </p>

            {% elif status == 402: %}
            <p>
                402
            </p>
            {% elif status == 611: %}
            <p>
                611
            </p>
            {% else %}
            <p>
                try again
            </p>
            {% endif %}
            <p>
                end of computation
            </p>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems you forgot an `{% endfor %}` before moving to `{% elif status == 402: %}`

Comment: You can see it better if you remove all the unnecessary stuff (gravitating towards a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). That would be the header, the paragraphs that have no dynamic data and things like that. To help see what's missing (or misplaced), you can add indentation between blocks as if it was Python code -- I find it helpful